# Image inside Grid of listview click or tap event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms cross platform app. 
I have listview inside that there is Grid and inside Grid there is image.
I want to fire event with selected item/image but I don't know how I can do that.

I have found that this can be achieved using `GestureRecognizers`  but how do I implement in my viewmodel

Please share some example with complete code, I mean xaml as well as code behind

Answer (score 7):

Try below code :

```
<ListView x:Name="InvoiceItemList" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemsSource="{Binding InvoiceLineItems}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
          <Image Source="overlaybg" Aspect="Fill">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="{Binding Source={x:Reference InvoiceItemList}, Path=BindingContext.RemoveInvoiceItemCommand}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
       </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

## EDIT

**ViewModel Code**

declare command

```
public ICommand RemoveInvoiceItemCommand { get; }
```

Initalize command in constructor

```
RemoveInvoiceItemCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
               RemoveInvoiceItem();
            });
```

Create function

```
 public void RemoveInvoiceItem()
    {
       //Do stuff
    }
```